# Spring AOP: logging and nested-methods

Tags: spring, logging, aop

I have written a simple Spring2.5 app to demo/test AOP; specifically, I want to log the entry and exit of every method of every class in a specific package.  This is what I have...

(note: I am using annotation-controllers; I am omitting details not directly-related to aop because my basic setup works fine -- I am only including aop-related details -- let me know if you need to see more)

---

***applicationContext.xml :***

```
(...)
<bean id="loggerInterceptor" class="aspect.LoggerInterceptor" />
(...)
```

***dispatcher-servlet.xml :***

```
(...)
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
(...)
```

***HomeController.java :***

```
public class HomeController() {

    public HomeController() { }

    public ModelAndView get() {
        System.out.println("In HomeController#get()...");

        this.somePrivateMethod();
        this.somePublicMethod();

        return new ModelAndView( "home" );
    }

    private void somePrivateMethod() {
        System.out.println("In HomeController#somePrivateMethod()...");
    }

    public void somePublicMethod() {
        System.out.println("In HomeController#somePublicMethod()...");
    }
}
```

***LoggerInterceptor.java :***

```
public class LoggerInterceptor {

    @Pointcut("execution(* controller.*.*(..))")
    private void anyOperationInControllerPackage() {
        /* nothing to do here;
         * this just defines that we want to catch all methods
         * in the controller-package
         */
    }

    @Around("anyOperationInControllerPackage()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("Entering " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "#" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() using arguments: " + Arrays.toString( joinPoint.getArgs() ) );

        try {

            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

            System.out.println("Leaving " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "#" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()." );

            return result;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;

        }

    }

}
```

---

Here is what I'm getting when HomeController#get() is invoked:

```
Entering controller.HomeController#get() using arguments: []
In HomeController#get()...
In HomeController#somePrivateMethod()...
In HomeController#somePublicMethod()...
Leaving controller.HomeController#get().
```

As you can see, the only method that's getting intercepted is HomeController#get().  When #get() calls #somePrivateMethod() or #somePublicMethod(), the interceptor doesn't catch those.  I would expect, at the very least, that #somePublicMethod() would also get caught (and since I'm using cglib, I would also expect that #somePrivateMethod() would get caught).

So I guess my question is what do I need to change/add in order to allow (at the very least) all public methods in the controller-package to get caught even when another method in that package called them and was itself caught first???

I hope that makes sense.
:D

---

### EDIT(25APR2011 @ 1:13PM)

***applicationContext.xml :***

```
(...)
<context:load-time-weaver />  <!-- added -->
<bean id="loggerInterceptor"... />
(...)
```

---

***aop.xml :***

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
        <include within="controller.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- use only this aspect for weaving -->
        <aspect name="aspect.LoggerInterceptor" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

---

***In Netbean's "Project Properties" under the "Run" tab I added this line to the "VM Options"*** :

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\bgresham\Documents\libraries\spring-framework-2.5\dist\weaving\spring-agent.jar
```

---

As before, I'm not getting any errors -- I just don't get the "nested"-logging I'm looking for.

???

Comment: I am having the same constraint in 2022 :) Is there a solution / workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Spring AOP, you *must* only call a method that's had an aspect applied to it via a reference returned by Spring, *not* through `this`, and I don't think you can apply pointcuts to private methods either (might be wrong on that last part). That's because Spring AOP applies the pointcuts through the proxy object, not by class rewriting (which is what AspectJ does). The benefit of that heavy restriction is that it is much easier to make it work in containers (I know from experience that Spring AOP works just fine inside Tomcat) because there's no warring over what bits are plugged in where.

The best way of doing this is by splitting the class definition so that you never call a method via `this`, but if that's not possible then you can always try giving a bean a Spring-derived reference to itself:

```
private HomeController self;
@Required
public void setSelf(HomeController self) { this.self = self; }

public ModelAndView get() {
    System.out.println("In HomeController#get()...");

    self.somePrivateMethod();
    self.somePublicMethod();

    return new ModelAndView( "home" );
}
```

(This is pretty neat; `self` is a keyword in a number of languages *but not Java* so it's relatively easy to remember what you're using it for.)

Comment: There's another gross trick mentioned in the Spring docs, but that involves massive amounts of coupling so I don't recommend even looking. The above though is relatively neat and it definitely works; I've got it in deployment.

Comment: @Donal: please forgive me, I'm a Spring-novice.  :)  But this example doesn't quite work in my environment.  I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: LifecycleException:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'self' is required for bean 'homeController'

Comment: I understand the traditional-route is to config your bean in xml and provide a <property...>-element; but I'm using almost exclusively auto-wiring and annotations, so HomeController doesn't appear in my xml (and I'd prefer to keep it that way).  Is there a way to get a reference to self via annotations?  Or maybe in HomeController#constructor() to get itself from spring's context?

Comment: @Bane: I actually went the other way in my apps, and explicitly list everything out. That lets my tools give me a neat visualization of the application architecture, which is useful for reports. :-) _As far as I'm aware_, it's enough to annotate the bean with `@Component` and the property setter with `@Autowired`, but I emphasize that I've not tried it.

Comment: @Donal: that didn't work.  :(  Nevertheless, I'm probably going to go your route anyways -- I only have like 3 controllers so it's no big deal -- if I go back and do so, I'll be sure to document the whole solution here for the next guy.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Donal: the self-trick didn't work even though I've declared the controller via xml.  But there's a good chance I'm doing it wrong.  In applicationContext.xml I added this: <bean id="self" class="controller.HomeController" ><property name="self" ref="self" /></bean> -- in dispatcher-servlet I commented-out the context:component-scan tag and between the context:annotation-config and aop:aspectj-autoproxy tags I added this tag: <bean id="homeController" class="controller.HomeController><property name="self" ref="self" /></bean> -- any thoughts???

Comment: @Bane: I don't think the order of declarations matters. What I *can* report is that the self trick works for me; I have it deployed and everything would fail miserably if it didn't work. :-)

Comment: :(  I do appreciate the help, though; it's a pretty neat idea.  :)

Comment: Thanks for this information - have spent the last 3 hours pulling my hair wondering why my aspect was not being fired. This information led me to locate the specific chapter in the Spring docs on this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies If anyone wants to read around the subject

Comment: Bane - Have you got the proper solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

You are using spring aop for aspect support. Spring aop will work only on spring beans. So, the pointcut does not work on the actual class instance i.e. when the controller calls any of its public or private method. In order to log all the methods in the controller, you need to use AspectJ for your aop support by enabling either load time or compile time weaving of all the classes that you want to intercept. 
Edit:

You would need the following for load time weaving :

aop.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">    
<aspectj>    
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug">    
        <include within="*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="your.logger.impl.LoggingImpl"/>
    </aspects>
  </aspectj>
```

This implies weaving in all your files ('within=*', modify as you wish) with the aspect/s specified. On load time you should see verbose information on weaving of classes.

Configurations in the spring configurations :

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect" 

            weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

Notice the weaving class has to be in the server library path and NOT your application path.

The above configurations should do what you are looking out to do.

Comment: First, I appreciate the reply!  :)  However, when I attempt to add that extra tag I notice that NB isn't showing it as a valid option.  Adding it anyways (and redeploying) gives me this error: ADM5603:Event listener error [ContainerBase.addChild: start: LifecycleException:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'mode' is not allowed to appear in element 'aop:aspectj-autoproxy'.]

Comment: So I removed it but added in support for aspectJ load-time weaving per a few online-guides I found.  But I'm still not getting the nested-logging I'm looking for.  Please see my detailed-edit to my original-post above.

Comment: @Bane If you are running it under a server like tomcat, then the LTW options are to be set with tomcat and not the JVM. The spring agent jvm options should work with a SE code.

Comment: @Turbochrgd: thank you for the feedback!  We're running under glassfish, so thank you for making that point for me.  As it stands, our environment is pretty strict -- I'm not sure I'll continue down this avenue since it requires modifying the server's env.  Great info for future newcomers, though, so thanks!  :)

Comment: @Bane In this case you should consider using compile time weaving before deploying the application